# Playwright won't execute

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, jestjs, playwright

I'm new to coding and automation tools. I have followed several install guides for playwright but to no avail (most recent one I have tried is the one on Carl Rippon dot com). I've been able to create scripts using the  npx playwright codegen [www.x.com](http://www.x.com) . However trying to execute these as either a .js or a .ts doesn't seem to do anything at all. I get errors that look like this:

```
    PS C:\Users\SamDavies\Desktop\playwright> node hello-world.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\SamDavies\Desktop\playwright\hello-world.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have the hello-world.js file inside that directory?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the contents of your desktop are not what you think they are. Especially on a corporate device you might find that your desktop is actually at:

```
C:\Users\SamDavies\OneDrive - Your Organisation Name\Desktop\
```

I'd recommend using tab completion or a directory listing to verify that the hello-world.js is definitely in your current working directory.